# how i can get the number of build and the revision of some project in jenkins?

Tags: java, jenkins

i want get this information from jenkins for use them in other application , this other application will have just a table with the follow information:

Nombre Proyecto -- Liga a la documentacion del proyecto -- # Build -- # revision
Maven project 1     http: .....                                20     20

but how can i get the # of build and revision.

I find some way to get it, is by the files that are in each project:
1.- nextBuilderNumber : with this file i can get the # build
2.- scm-polling.log:with this file i can get the # of revision

but with the file 1 i'm having problems because the file number 1 don't have extension, but in properties it say's that is a plaint text object, so i can't read it. but if i change the extension of the file now it works. but when jenkins compile the project again generate the file without extension.

this is the part of the source code for read the file:

```
enter code here for (int i = 0; i < enlaces.length; i++) {
        try {         
            fr = new FileReader (ruta+enlaces[i]+"/nextBuildNumber.txt");         
            br = new BufferedReader(fr);         
            int numeroBuild;
            numeroBuild=new Integer(br.readLine()); 
            orderList[i]=new Datos(enlaces[i],numeroBuild,10);                                                    
            }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{            
        try{                               
            fr.close();                                  
           }catch (Exception e2){ 
                e2.printStackTrace();
           }
        }               
    }
```

Comment: for every project i read the file and later i'm going to use the array orderList with a dataTable to show the information

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins already set some variables in the environment, you can use them. From [the wiki](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project):

> When a Jenkins job executes, it sets some environment variables that
>   you may use in your shell script, batch command, Ant script or Maven
>   POM 1. The following table contains a list of all of these environment
>   variables.

There's the `BUILD_NUMBER` and `SVN_REVISION`, for example.

Comment: and later how can i read the values of that environment variables? for use them in other application JSF

Comment: You can use a script that calls your Java and store the info in the database.

Comment: thanks i already found the way to do this , now my application is working perfect, i read the values from the files that are into the folder of each project. the files are nextBuildNumber and scm-polling.log